# Keylogging host from virtual machine

Tags: virtualization, keyloggers

Can a keylogger in a virtual machine (guest OS) capture keystrokes in host OS? Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

No, not unless there were a critical VM-escape vulnerability in the VM hypervisor.

Comment: Not even through the shared network?

Comment: A shared network does not send keystroke information, so no. You'd have to compromise the host through the shared network (VM escape) like the answer states.

Answer (score 1):

Are there ways to capture host keystrokes from a guest? Sure, but only in the case of a critical vulnerability or perhaps a misconfiguration.

Here's an example: a user running a GNU/Linux host wants to run some untrusted applications in a VM. They want to share files between host and guest, so they decide to pass `/tmp` to the guest. Problem is, the host is running an X11 display server, which doesn't offer isolation between applications, and has a socket file in `/tmp/.X11-unix`. Assuming the guest has the ability to write to the file, it can log all keystrokes from the host user's X session using the method outlined [here](https://theinvisiblethings.blogspot.com/2011/04/linux-security-circus-on-gui-isolation.html?m=1).

While this configuration is unlikely, it does indicate that it is possible to do this given the right circumstances.